# "Хлеб по цене завода"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Недавно сфотографировал вот эту забавную вывеску:

[image]

Понятно, что имеется в виду, что цена такая, как на заводе, но звучит так, словно хлеб стоит столько же, сколько и завод. А как правильно нужно сформулировать это заявление?
Заранее спасибо за ответы.

Comment: Аналогичное наблюдение: "Мы изготовим шкафы по вашим размерам". Шкаф моего размера - это гроб, что ли? ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы убрать двусмысленность достаточно сделать хлеб словом общего рода, коим он в данном контексте и является. Фраза - *Хлеб по ценам завода-производителя* - двусмысленностей уже не имеет. Мне правда фраза слух не режет и в представленном варианте, "цена завода-производителя" уже давно стала клише, на которое не обращаешь внимание.

Answer (score 3):

А я бы написал проще: "Хлеб по заводской цене"

Comment: Тогда непонятно, что имеются в виду цены производителя.

Answer (score 1):

Родительный беспредложный падеж имеет два значения: признаковое (какой? чей?) и объектное (вопросы косвенных падежей). Иногда разница между ними незаметна, например: картина художника (кого? чья?), в других случаях верно только одно значение: песня (какая?) года  и решение (чего?) задачи. Это хорошо видно на предложениях вида: Композитор сочинил пьесу:сочинение (чего?) пьесы и сочинение (чье?) композитора. Также: Завод оценил хлеб: цена  (чего?) хлеба, цена (какая?) завода (заводская).
Также для Т.п.: резать хлеб (как?) ломтиками (чем?) ножом - признаковое и объектное значения одного падежа.

Answer (score 0):

У меня двойственное чувство от этого вопроса. 
С одной стороны не покидает ощущение явной придирки, ибо реально никакой двусмысленности тут не возникает, вряд ли кто всерьез примет эту рекламу за предложение заплатить "цену завода". Тем более, что у завода, которые не выставлен на продажу, есть стоимость, но никак не цена.
С другой - при всей своей понятности фраза все-таки не есть образец правильной и культурной речи... И - увы! - предложенные варианты правки ощущение этакой топорности до конца не снимают. 
Возможно, что более правильно было бы сказать "по оптовым ценам завода" или еще вернее - "по отпускным ценам завода" (в принципе это разные вещи), но это скорее запутает покупателя, чем подстегнет его. Самым "правильным" с точки зрения сути ценообразования было бы написать честно "без торговой наценки", но это опять-таки на человека разбирающегося хотя бы в азах. 
Из всего из этого заключаю, что тут вернее всего будет довериться чутью продавцов или рекламщиков, родивших этот оборот.

Answer (score 0):

- От завода-производителя с минимальной наценкой.